# erro: 'List ' is abstract cannot be defined

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos

Eu pretendo em utilizar java com Android Studio para fazer uma calculadora, porém, toda vez que clico num botão adiciono para uma lista os valores desses botões.

Mas tendo erro na declaração da lista. alguém me pode ajudar?

[image: Foto do meu programa com o erro]

Comment: A única maneira de usar `C# ` com  `Android ` é utilizando `Xamarin Studio` ou  `Visual Studio ` com  `plugin  Xamarin `

Comment: Isso não é C#, é Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não está programando C#, isso ai é Java.

Você não pode instanciar `List` em Java, porque `List` é uma classe abstrata. Você pode instanciar um `ArrayList`.

```
List<Character> Conta = new ArrayList<Character>();
```